# error compiling gcc: undefined reference to libc_name_p

Tags: gcc, compilation

When compiling GCC it is possible to get very far in the build process only to hiccup on an error complaining about the lack of gperf installed. After installing gperf and running, I hit  an "undefined reference to `libc_name_p`." I've looked at the solutions [here](http://blackfin.uclinux.org/gf/project/toolchain/forum/?_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=26798&action=ForumBrowse) and [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2007-01/msg00100.html) but they weren't helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When gperf wasn't installed, the compilation script ran the command anyway but generated a blank `./gcc/cp/cfns.h`. Since this file was newer than the source (`./gcc/cp/cfns.gperf`) the makefile left it alone and never regenerated the 'real' file when you actually had gperf. To continue, run `rm ./gcc/cp/cfns.h` and try again.

Comment: Yeah, it drove me nuts. Glad to be of help!